# Another way of Thread.sleep with Do While Loops in Java?

Tags: java, loops, netbeans, do-while, thread-sleep

Whenever I write `Thread.sleep(500);` in my code, it always tells me this sometimes causes problems to use `Thread.sleep();`. Is there another way to delay time before certain things. If so, can you give me the code and explanation. Thank you

Comment: What "problems" does it complain about...other than throwing an `InterruptedException`...?

Comment: Better try to figure out and solve the problem first, before trying to  work around it.

Comment: paste your code which is giving problems to you it throws InterruptedException you should handle that

Comment: @MadProgrammer In which case most of the alternatives will have the same "problem".  Perhaps it is time to learn how to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you don't show us any code and you don't mention what "it" is.  (As in "it always tells me ...".)  This makes a specific answer impossible.

---

It most likely that the problem referred to is that `sleep` makes your code either wasteful or unresponsive.  A common "hack" used to make a thread wait for some condition is to repeatedly call sleep and then test the condition.  The problem is that if the condition becomes true while you are sleeping, the thread will still be held up until the sleep interval expires.  If you make the sleep interval smaller, then you "burn" more CPU cycles with wakeup / test / sleep iterations.

If you are trying to implement a "wait for some condition to become true", then the efficient way to do it is to either use `wait()` and `notify()` (or `notifyAll()`), or an appropriate higher level synchronization class.

The classic Java pattern is like this:

```
    // waiting for the condition
    synchronized (obj) {
        while (!condition) {
            obj.wait();
        }
    }

    ...

    // updating the condition ...
    synchronized (obj) {
        // do something that makes condition true
        obj.wait();
    }
```

Note that the use of `synchronized` is essential if you use wait/notify.

Comment: When I say "it", I mean the Netbeans Compiler Hint helper. I then hover over the icon to see the suggestion. The hint helper tells me Thread.sleep CAN malfunction and not work correctly.

Comment: Please, by all means, edit your question with the source! Don't post it in comments, it's unreadable.

Comment: @user2827616 - I'm ignoring those unreadable comments.  If you want someone to comment on your code, format it properly and add it to the Question.

Answer (score 0):

`Condition` interface can be useful to let other threads notify you about specific events and ask the current thread to get "parked" till then. `Condition` interface also has a methods called `waitUntil(Date deadline)` - which causes current thread to wait until the deadline elapses.

Are you waiting for some other thread to perform some activity and wait till then? Use any blocking data structure like `BlockingQueue` or other advanced synchronizers like `CountdownLatch`.

If just waiting for some thread to complete its execution use `join()`.

As mentioned bay MadProgrammer and alfasin, its important to know what you are trying to achieve and what is the problem in `sleep()` you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to happen in the near future, using sleep repeatedly is a bad thing. For once it does not guarantee to be "on time", and for second it can be interrupted at any time, causing your program to malfunction.

If you have one part of your code that needs to be executed repeatedly, using a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) can solve that perfectly. If you have multiple and different parts of code that need to be executed with given delays, you should use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). You can either use the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor directly or - more conveniently - use the ExecutorService.

You can easily circumvent threading issues by just using a single thread. However threading isn't that difficult in Java if you use the right tools.